# Oracle SQL - search for specific records

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm wondering how to do the following:

So, I have here an example table:

```
ID:   Name:          Occupation:     Startdate:    Enddate: 

1     John           Journalist      01/01/2000    01/01/2000
2     John           Baker           01/01/2002    01/01/2004
3     John           Butcher         01/01/2004    (null)
4     Mark           Baker           05/03/2000    (null)
5     Petrus         Lawyer          01/01/2001    01/01/2002
6     Petrus         Baker           01/01/2002    (null)
7     Andre          Journalist      01/01/1999    01/01/2000
8     Andre          Baker           01/01/2000    (null)
```

So, here's what I want: I want to find the names of all the persons who have first been a journalist and then switched to being a baker. So, I don't want to find people who were just bakers, nor do I wanna find people who have first been a journalist, then a baker, and then went on to being a butcher. So, basically, I want the query to return the two records of Andre.

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: I should mention that this db is not to be edited, so no inserts or anything that would alter the db in any way, what I want is as simple a select query as possible, if possible.

Comment: Have you tried to write a Query? At first find who was a Baker, then who is journalist and start_date of Journalist is > end_date of Baker

Comment: the start&enddates are unknown to me, as well as their names. What I need to find, is a list of anyone who has first been a journalist and then moved on to being a baker. I can't search based on start&enddates.

Comment: You don't need to know the startdate&enddate value. Just compare the field. Try to write something and then post it. We can start with what you write!

Comment: What if someone was a journalist, then a butcher and finally a baker, or if they were a butcher, then a journalist and finally a baker; would you want to see both rows, neither, one or other of them?

Comment: @Boneist: no, I wouldn't want either of those records. The person I'm looking for has to have a very specific career: first journalist, then baker. Exactly this career.

Answer (score 1):

This uses a trick of your data, which is that the `enddate` of the previous occupation matches the `startdate` of the next one:

```
with candidates as ( 
    select name, enddate from your_table
    where occupation = 'Journalist'
    intersect 
    select name, startdate from your_table
    where occupation = 'Baker'
    and enddate is null -- this is current record
)
select name
from candidates
/
```

This won't work for people who started as journalists, became butchers, then became bakers. But according to your comment that's not something you'd want to do.

---

In real life bounded date ranges commonly don't overlap. That is, the `startdate` should be `enddate+1`. After all, people generally don't start a new job at lunchtime!

Comment: *In real life bounded date ranges commonly don't overlap*. Do you consider ending at 12PM and starting at 12PM overlapping? Then you need to add a second (or millisecond or microsecond) to the next start. The common way to store intervals in a database is `[inclusive/exclusive[`, regardless if it's dates or timestamps, much easier to implement without possible gaps.

Comment: @dnoeth -  I think it depends on the grain of the column: if time is a component then, yes, the seconds should be correct. Date ranges are notoriously difficult to implement and I have seen all sorts of things in my career. However I maintain that in most cases and certainly in this case, `enddate` should be the last day worked as a journalist and `startdate` should be the first day worked as a baker, and they should be different days. Otherwise you have a problem answering the question, 'what job was John doing on 01-JAN-2002?'

Comment: If you use `BETWEEN`
, yes, but not with `searched_date >= start_date and searched_date < end_date`. Standard SQL (and some DBMSes) supports *temporal tables*, which greatly simplify maintenance of those *Slowly Changing Dimensions*. Did you ever have to switch an implementation from DATE-based to TIMESTAM-based? Or some tables are the former, others the latter, how to tell the users there are two different implementations :-)

Comment: I just noticed that your working on Oracle, which started supporting Temporal Tables in 12c :-)

Comment: @dnoeth - obviously there are many ways to write the SQL. My issue is that the data model is wrong. What is the last day John worked as a Journalist? Well it's the day before the value we have in `enddate`. Fnord. And my reading of [Temporal Validity in Oracle 12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_design.htm#ADFNS967) is that it wants prior `enddate` less than next `startdate`.

Comment: Oracle's documentation on Temporal is, ahem, *sparse*, but I found this: *If the value of neither column is NULL, then the value of the start time column must be earlier than the value of the end time column. The row is considered valid for all time values that occur on or after the value of the start time column, and up to, but not including, the value of the end time column.* https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from
 (
    select tab.*,
       count(*) over (partition by Name) as cnt,
       first_value(Occupation) over (partition by Name order by StartDate) as occ#1
       max(Occupation) over (partition by Name) as occ#2 -- simpler than LAST_VALUE
    from tab
 ) st
where cnt = 2             -- excatly 2 rows
  and occ#1 ='Journalist' -- 1st occupation
  and occ#2 = 'Baker'     -- 2nd occupation
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
WITH tbl
     AS (SELECT '1'          id,
                'John'       name,
                'Journalist' occupation,
                '01/01/2000' startdate,
                '01/01/2000' enddate
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '2', 'John', 'Baker', '01/01/2002', '01/01/2004' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '3',
                'John',
                'Butcher',
                '01/01/2004',
                NULL
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '4',
                'Mark',
                'Baker',
                '05/03/2000',
                NULL
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '5', 'Petrus', 'Lawyer', '01/01/2001', '01/01/2002' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '6',
                'Petrus',
                'Baker',
                '01/01/2002',
                NULL
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '7',
                'Andre',
                'Journalist',
                '01/01/1999',
                '01/01/2000'
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '8',
                'Andre',
                'Baker',
                '01/01/2000',
                NULL
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT id,
       name,
       occupation,
       startdate,
       enddate
  FROM (SELECT t.*,
               ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY startdate) rn
          FROM tbl t) mn_tbl
 WHERE     name IN
              (SELECT name
                 FROM (SELECT t.*,
                              ROW_NUMBER ()
                                 OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY startdate)
                                 rn
                         FROM tbl t)
                WHERE rn = 1 AND occupation = 'Journalist') -- First occupation was Journalist
       AND EXISTS
              (SELECT name
                 FROM (SELECT t.*,
                              ROW_NUMBER ()
                                 OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY startdate)
                                 rn
                         FROM tbl t)
                WHERE rn = 2 AND name = mn_tbl.name AND occupation = 'Baker') -- Second occupation was Baker
       AND NOT EXISTS
              (SELECT name
                 FROM (SELECT t.*,
                              ROW_NUMBER ()
                                 OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY startdate)
                                 rn
                         FROM tbl t)
                WHERE rn > 2 AND name = mn_tbl.name)    -- No more occupations
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not pretty and it cannot be extended beyond two occupations... but it works :)

Counting distinct will get rid of all people who had more than 2 careers. Then the ugly trick is comparing the startdate of the journalist carer to that of the baker.

```
select name, count(*)  
  from candidates
 group 
    by name
having count(distinct occupation) = 2 -- Only had two occupations
   and min(case when occupation = 'Journalist' then startdate end) /* First Journalist */
     < min(case when occupation = 'Baker'      then startdate end) /* Then baker */
```